# When to use angular template and when symfony template

Tags: angularjs, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm newbie web developer and I wonder what better and if it is a good question at all

I can retrieve the information that I need from the server side and make the template with angular, and I can do it with symfony too. whats better? whats the difference? when to use what? 
what about forms? should I do it with symfony features or just with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look the following points

- You should use Angularjs template system. otherwise, the powerful feature of Directives.
- Angularjs is decoupled with serverside code.
- Angularjs only expects data (as `JSON`) from service end..not any `HTML`.
  So template should be angularjs way.
- So every service response from symfony should be `JSON`.
- Angularjs totally avoiding to add `HTML containers (through ajax)` into web
  pages. So here you can not use symfony template.

Comment: so from your comment I can understand that I shouldn't work at all with the template engine of symfony. is it right?